# Bind C-f to next-field only when expanding a snippet in yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

Is it possible to bind C-f and C-b to yasnippet's next-field and prev-field functions only when currently inside of a snippet expansion? I've tried looking for something like a `yas-snippet-map`. `yas-minor-mode-map` won't work because it'll remap C-f and C-b whenever I have yas enabled.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All I really need is some way to tell that I'm currently in a snippet expansion from Elisp.. Once I have that, rolling my own function won't be too difficult.

Comment: You need `yas--snippets-at-point`.  Have a look at `aya-open-line`
from https://github.com/abo-abo/auto-yasnippet for a sample
implementation.